# I need help with a riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I rhyme with alliteration and imitation
>   Latin word Dictionary
>   clone, reproduction, duplicate
>   I said the light will reveal what's in the dark
>   as it will all tie together
>   you question me, but don't know my name
>   I may not be what I seem
>   but neither is James
>   Not big, Wayne (We figured out it was Lil' Wayne; I'm not human)
>   10-12-10
>   Not old, rhymes with honey
>   Side by side
>   Same distance continously
>   All existing matter.
>   You.
>   *Not* me.

Comment: I'm not sure if the "story" or "rhyme" tags apply here, or "cipher" - have you checked out the tag description pages?

Comment: It sounds like you're saying this is not your original creation, but copied from somewhere else.  If that's the case, we require proper attribution.

Comment: Does this all refer to the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the lines have led me to a possible solution:

> simulation

It rhymes with alliteration and imitation, and is very closely related to the concepts of a clone, reproduction, or duplicate.

I said the light will reveal what's in the dark

> maybe some kind of a physics/particle system simulation?

All existing matter

> there are scientific theories that our entire universe is a simulation.